# AngularJS $resource - update array within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb, api

I am trying to figure out how to update an array within a javascript object using an API. As an example, I can pull a full endpoint of */api/posts/:id* and get the following results:

```
    {"_id":"56521356177af21100960105",
"user":"564bbd2da851f0aaeb7746c5",
"description":"'Taking You Higher' Pt. 3 Support here... http://bit.ly/YJBeIg So a year after 'Taking You Higher' Rameses B and I decided to put out another summery progres...",
"title":"'Taking You Higher Pt. 2' (Progressive House Mix) - YouTube","comment":"This is a great mix.","url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heJBwBUStXU","__v":0,
"created":"2015-11-22T19:11:18.760Z",
"group":["564fddfbf5d334fc0f6b4093"]}
```

I want to focus on the "group" array within the object. I am looking for a way to update the array by both adding and removing items using AngularJs. As far as I can tell, I will most likely need to use *$resource* instead of *$http.* However, I do not know what how this should be written.

Here is what I have so far in my controller:

```
myApp.factory('groupsInPost', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/posts/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT' // this method issues a PUT request
    }
  });
});
```

.

```
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$q', '$log', '$filter', 'groupsInPost',
function($scope, $http, $timeout, $q, $log, $filter, groupsInPost ) { 
...
$scope.updateGroup = function(post_id) {
        var favorite = $scope.favorite;

        $scope.groups = groupsInPost.get({ id: post_id }, function() {
          // $scope.groups is fetched from server and is an instance of groupsInPost
          console.log($scope.groups.data)
          //$scope.groups.$update(function() {
            //updated in the backend
        });

        // $http.put('/api/posts/' + post_id, groups.push(group_id)).success(function(response) {
        //  refreshPost();
        // });
    };
...
});
```

My current problem, as you might immediately expect is that my API is not  sending back an array as $resource is expecting. I am not sure where to go from here. If you have any insight, it would be very helpful.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a bit confused on why you call `$scope.groups.data`. Is `data` part of your API response to the `GET` request?

Also as per the posted code you retrieve a list of groups *during* your update call. Since the `$resource` related to the `posts` shouldn't this be done before? At the time you load the posts seems more reasonable.

On your commented line you push a `group_id` to groups list. Where does it come from?

Assuming you want to keep this flow you currently have my suggestion would be something like this:

```
var group_id = 1;
$scope.post = groupsInPost.get({ id: post_id }, function() {
  $scope.post.group.push(group_id);

  $scope.post.$update(function() {
    // updated in the backend
  });
});
```

Please let me know if I missed something on the question so I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: this code worked perfectly. Thank you very much. In regards to your question, the extra code within the controller was simply extra things I had previously tried. I simply had left those in as a reference to what had previously been attempted. 

I do have one follow-up. The code you provided shows me how I can push content to the array as requested. I am also looking for a way to remove certain items from the array. So, say you added the group_id to the array, what might the code look like to remove the group_id?

Thank you in advance?

Comment: You will need to first find its index: `var i = $scope.post.group.indexOf(group_id);`

And then remove it: `if (i !== -1) { $scope.post.group.splice(i, 1); }`